# Key Error 0 while working with join() on series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have got this pandas series called `"tokenized_data"`

[image]

Now I am trying to do the below operation:

```
for i in range(len(tokenized_data)):
    tokenized_data[i] = ' '.join(tokenized_data[i])
```

However, I am getting the

> key Error:0

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: s.str.join(' ')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
tokenized_data =  tokenized_data.str.join(' ')
```

Or:

```
tokenized_data =  tokenized_data.apply(' '.join)
```

The problem of your solution is that the loop `tokenized_data[i]` cannot select range values, because index values of Series are different.

```
tokenized_data = pd.Series([['would','have','hard'], ['worth','seek']], index=[77,101])

for i in range(len(tokenized_data)):
    print (i)
    #cannot select index 0, because not exist (indices are `77` and `101`)
    print (tokenized_data[i])
```

Select by position should work here, but it is better to use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
for i in range(len(tokenized_data)):
    tokenized_data.iloc[i] = ' '.join(tokenized_data.iloc[i])
```

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the top of your answer :( My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jezrael for letting me know where I was going wrong.

I just did the minor change in the code after that which was ....

<>`tokenized_data= tokenized_data.reset_index(drop=True)`

which helped in resetting the index and my code worked like wonder.